# Reassign the question to a new category in the Review triage, to undo one's mistake

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

While reviewing the questions in the Review triage I unintentionally marked a question to the **Requires Editing** category which I think should've gone into the **Looks Okay** category. So I started looking for some way to undo my action or reassign the question to the category where I think it should belong, but there wasn't any or maybe I was unable to find it. It felt bad as it felt like I was being unfair to the OP. So is there a way to make things right and if there isn't, shouldn't something be introduced to rectify one's action in such a case?

Comment: I don't think that it's such a big deal. Personally, if I see one grammar mistake, I click "requires editing". There's always room for editing.

Comment: @Laurel what if there actually was no room for editing?

Comment: I just tagged a (first post) question that it didn't need anything because it already had a down vote and a (polite) comment explaining why it wasn't appropriate for SO, so it didn't need _further_ work. But then I realized that my vote probably seemed to disagree with the comment. But I couldn't fix it.

Comment: I think this question actually has a broader relevance: I have made similar mistakes (obviously, only rarely) in different review queues and would have liked to have been able to go back and change my 'verdict'. Could this even be made a feature request?

Comment: Once you've completed a review, there's no way to change the review result which you submitted. For some actions which are part of the review process, you can reverse that action (e.g. voting/flagging to close as part of "Unsalvageable" can be reverted by retracting the vote/flag, but you can't change the "Unsalvageable"). For some queues, there are some things which you can do to partially compensate. For example in Triage, if "Requires Editing" is the final result of the review, you can try to find the new review in Help & Improvement and edit the post, removing it from H&I.